# how to maintain different file name at Apache POI keyword

Tags: apache-poi, katalon-studio

this is the keyword file which read excel data, testmatrix-test1.xlsx.

now I have 2 files, testmatrix-test1.xlsx , testmatrix-test2.xlsx , at the same project repo.

how do I make changes on this, so the script call the right keyword?

```
public class readexcel {


    //method defined for reading a cell
    @Keyword
    private static  findData(String rowName, String columnName) throws IOException {
        String cellValue = ReadCellData(rowName, columnName);
        System.out.println(cellValue);
    }


    private static String ReadCellData(String rowName, String columnName) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(RunConfiguration.getProjectDir() + "/Data Files/testmatrix-test1.xlsx");
        Workbook workbook=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Row firstRow = sheet.getRow(0);
        int rowNameColIdx = findColumnIdx("Automation TC", firstRow);
        int colNameColIdx = findColumnIdx(columnName, firstRow);

        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        rowIterator.next();
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            if (rowName.equals(row.getCell(rowNameColIdx).getStringCellValue())) {
                return row.getCell(colNameColIdx).getStringCellValue();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static int findColumnIdx(String text, Row row) {
        for (Cell cell : row) {
            if (text.equals(cell.getStringCellValue())) {
                return cell.getColumnIndex();
            }
        }
        return -1;

}
```

test1 and test2 script to call the keyword.

```
def exceldata = CustomKeywords.'test.readexcel.ReadCellData'("row2", "columnC")
```

Comment: Where is the file being passed to the custom method? Does this even work with one sheet?

Comment: not about maintaining multiple sheet. this is maintaining multiple files. the worksheet working fine  int rowNameColIdx = findColumnIdx("Automation TC", firstRow);.